# My program hangs on pthread_rwlock_wrlock

Tags: multithreading, locking, pthreads

I have a 9-threaded program which hangs after sometime on pthread_rwlock_wrlock

```
pthread_rwlock_wrlock(p_lock)
write(file_handler, buff, len);
pthread_rwlock_unlock(p_lock);
```

After sometimes, my program hangs and all the threads are found to be blocked for lock.
However, the same program seems to be working fine when I replaced rwlock with mutex.

Comment: Probably some other thread holds a read lock and won't release it.

Comment: I haven't used this lock anywhere else. It is only present in this particular code section.

Comment: Oh? Then what purpose does it serve? Preventing interleaving?